# How to resume browser session or use existing browser window with Selenium-Python?

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

I've got some code that looks like this:

```
print 'Starting browser'
browser = webdriver.Firefox()

print 'Loading %s' % base_url
browser.get(base_url)

try:
    username_el = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#username')
    username_el.send_keys(credentials['username'])
    password_el = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#password')
    password_el.send_keys(credentials['password'])
    password_el.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
    print 'Logging in'
    browser.get(base_url)
except NoSuchElementException:
    print 'Already logged in'
    pass
```

The problem is that it has to log in every time (never trips the exception). This has two problems:

1. It makes my tests take longer because I have to wait for it to log in each time
2. It hits the server more than it needs to

So, I'd like to either save and resume my browser session, or leave the browser open and have Selenium take control of that.

Is this possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 1):

i'd try using get_cookies() to grab any session cookies, saving that somewhere that'll persistent between browser sessions (disk or whatever), and re-adding the cookies using add_cookie() when you pull up a new browser session.

haven't tested this though...

Comment: I will try it. I tried manually stealing the cookies from my "real" browser and copying those in, but that didn't work. I'll try nabbing them with `get_cookies`...maybe the session is a bit different.

Comment: Does indeed work. Reason it was failing before because [the docs](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html?highlight=add_cookie#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.add_cookie) are full of lies.  It actually expects a dictionary with name,value,domain,host,expires keys, not a key/value pair.