# Python with selenium: rerun on pre-existing browser

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

I'm using Python with Selenium 2.44.  When the test fails, I can't just uncomment all the code before the failure when debugging it, because the driver will not be declared for the browser.  Therefore, whenever I try fixing something, I always have to open a new browser in the test case.  This is rather... slow since I have to login, which adds an additional 30 seconds (not devastating, but annoying).  I want to know if there's a way for me to just continue a session, or do something that allows me to start the test midway through (so if I have the webpage open already, I can just immediately start clicking things rather than opening a new browser).  Is this possible?

For example, if I had something along the lines of:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("google.com")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='gbqfq']").send_keys("cats" + Keys.RETURN)
```

This should open Firefox, go to google, and search for cats.  Pretend like there's a ton of stuff you have to do before you can actually make it to the google page, though.  Now if it were to fail on the search for cats, the only way I would be able to test to see if I fixed the code would be to rerun the test (`webdriver.Firefox()` would open a new browser).  Rather than that, assuming I'd still have google open, I'd like the selenium test to just start off on the previous browser and google page (therefore saying the first step in the code would be the `send_keys("cats")`).  Is this possible?

I think that this was a similar question, but it didn't get checked off as answered: [How to resume browser session or use existing browser window with Selenium-Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11233225/how-to-resume-browser-session-or-use-existing-browser-window-with-selenium-pytho)

This one also seems similar, only pertaining to Java: [How do I rerun Selenium 2.0 (webdriver) tests on the same browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5383958/how-do-i-rerun-selenium-2-0-webdriver-tests-on-the-same-browser)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into pdb: https://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html

Placing this in your code will stop the progression of the test as is until you tell it to continue in your shell.

Using your code snippit:

```
from pdb import set_trace
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("google.com")
set_trace()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='gbqfq']").send_keys("cats" + Keys.RETURN)
```

will stop your execution after getting the url, allow you to tinker, and then continue from where the test left off.

Alternatively, while debugging, you can just remove the driver.quit() statement, wherever it happens to be, which will keep the browser open wherever your assertion failed. But if you're using a framework like Django with the LiveTestServer Client, you won't have access to browse the site further. pdb will allow you to keep the test server active.

Comment: that... is... awesome... how have I not know about this lol thanks!